# Programmatically detecting between Adobe Air and Adobe Flex in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex3

I have some shared code between an Adobe AIR App and an Adobe Flex App.

On one line of this code, the program must behave differently depending on if it is running within the Air runtime, or the Flex runtime.

How can I programmatically detect the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (Capabilities.playerType == "Desktop") {
  trace("I'm running on AIR");
}
```

See the [`Capabilities` documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType).

Comment: The import for this is Flash.System.Capabilities